# where is make and man pages under MacOS Lion?

Tags: macos, makefile, osx-lion, manpage

I just installed MacOS X Lion and XCode (which now needs to be downloaded from the Apple store). It seems that `make` and the `man` pages are missing. Does anybody know where they are?

Comment: I have MacOS X lion and the man pages are there. Can you at least post the commands you are attempting to execute in the terminal?

Comment: I have MacOS X lion and the man pages are there. Can you at least post the commands you are attempting to execute in the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XCode install is a two-step process -- it sounds like you haven't run the "Install XCode" application yet, as that's what installs the utilities and manual pages. You can find it in your Applications folder.

Comment: Wow. That is so not-obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to mark the question as "answered" if that solved your issue!